# where to import pygame package in colaboratory?

Tags: python, pygame, google-colaboratory

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
2 import sys
3
----> 4 import pygame
5
6 from settings import Settings

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

All libraries (modules, per say) you use on Python need to be installed first. The only exception is with native modules, which is not the case.

If you are not using anaconda, you have to use **pip** to install.

Go to your terminal, and type:

```
pip install pygame
```